# Find length of locus of given inverse trigonometric function

Tags: functions, trigonometry, inverse-function, locus

> Consider equation $\sin ^{-1}(px)+ \cos^{-1} (qxy)= sin ^{-1} y$. Let $L$ is the length of locus of point $A(x,y)$ when $p=1=q+1$. Then what is the value of $A$.

My approach :

We have $p=1$ and $q=0$
Hence the equation turns to $$\sin ^{-1}(x)+ \frac {\pi}{2}= sin ^{-1} y$$
Taking sine both sides
The equation turns to 
$$\cos(\sin ^{-1} x)=y$$
Hence 
$$\cos(\cos ^{-1} \sqrt {1-x^2})=y$$
Hence $$\sqrt {1-x^2}=y$$
So we get locus as $$x^2+y^2=1$$
Hence The length of this locus (circle in this case) is $2\pi$

But the answer is given as $\frac {\pi}{2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $x$ takes all values in $[-1,1]$, the left-hand side of your equation varies from $0$ to $\pi$. But the left-hand side cannot exceed $\pi/2$, hence $x$ is bounded to $[-1,0]$ and $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}\in[0,1]$. The locus is then a quarter circle and its length is $\pi/2$.

Comment: So is the answer given in the textbook wrong.

Comment: Yes it is, if the text of the question is exactly the one you wrote.

Comment: No, I was wrong: I hadn't considered that $\sin^{-1}y$ can only take values in $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$. I corrected my answer.